# not allow typing in a text field html, can use JavaScript or any function of html

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I have a text field html and it has a datepicker. It not allow typing characters but numbers allow. I need that it not allow numbers.

Comment: Did you try with the readonly attribute?

Comment: What are you exactly asking ? Do you want to type just numbers in that text field ?

Comment: i need that in my text field not allow type anything, but allow normally date picker

Comment: Why doesn't the readonly attribute work?

Comment: @bsayegh My guess is that his datepicker works by putting the date into the input. So readonly wouldn't work since nothing would end up being posted.

Comment: exactly, i want that my text field allow at datepicker to function normally, but not allow type anymore, because the datepicker not allow type characters but allow numbers

Comment: @user3444057 I'm sorry but what you want is unusual, bad for accessibility, and won't work with javascript disabled. I recommend that you validate the date instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one function would do what you want :

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("date").onkeyup=function(){
   return false;
}
```

And here is **HTML** :

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

See this [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y5Fpn/1/). Hope this helps.

Comment: If you dont want anything to be typed then just change `onkeyup` with `onkeydown` .

Comment: @user3444057 Mark it as answer to help others if that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Onchange event and then check if the input is a number
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp